# Подскажите живые Android сообщества

Tags: android

Подскажите живое русскоязычное сообщество Android разработчиков (формат не важен, группа в скайпе/группы в соц сетях/форумы и т.п.). Уже пол года занимаюсь разработкой андроид приложений, но еще ни разу не попадалось живое сообщество. Либо группы в Google+ в которых новый пост раз в пол года, либо маленькие группки в разных соц сетях.

Так же интересны англоязычные форумы/группы в соцсетях и т.п.

Буду благодарен за любую инфу.

Comment: в социалке только вот тут сижу(но щас очень редко) https://vk.com/androiddevelopers А чем ru SO и SO не сообщество?

Comment: Не знаю про "ru SO и SO", можно ссылки?

Comment: @IvanDembicki ru so - ru.stackoverflow.com, SO - stackoverflow.com

Comment: вы как раз на этом сайте находитесь)

Comment: Тупанул =) На понял сокращения =)

Comment: SO подходит только для вопросов/ответов, а мне же хочется следить за новыми тенденциями, смотреть кто какими проектами хвастается и т.п. И чтоб все это было в одном месте и не подписываться на кучу групп в которых 90% контента не по интересующей меня теме.

Comment: http://forum.startandroid.ru/